# Return the value from a mongoose find

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to render a template when i check the link for view a profile (*for example going to* http://localhost:3000/user/testuser`), all ok going to the routes but the values don't being showed on the page. This is my code:

```
Account.find({ username: req.params.username }, function(err, userWatch){
        res.render('account/profile',{
          title : userWatch.username,
          user : req.user,
          watchUser : userWatch,
        });
```

Comment: `console.log(userWatch)` ?

Comment: [ { following: [],
    favourites: [],
    __v: 0,
    emailAccount: 'testuser@mysite.com',
    username: 'testuser',
    _id: 572b541f6693b24023a8dcac } ]

Comment: it's an `array` and you are referencing it as an `object`. Use fineOne to fetch the data

Comment: Use findOne instead of find to get single result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Account.find()` that returns the array of objects. You should use `Account.findOne()` to fetch data, if you want either one or none objects.